# how to be input into the new column

Tags: php, mysql

has been running with separate inputs ( , ) in a single column.

how to be input into the new column??

form input :

```
<form method="post" action="collect_vals.php">
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
    <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
    <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
    <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
    <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
    <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
</div>
</form>
```

insert to database :

```
<?php
//Open a new connection to the MySQL server
$mysqli = new mysqli('host','username','password','database_name');

//Output any connection error
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}

$capture_field_vals ="";
if(isset($_POST["mytext"])){   
    foreach($_POST["mytext"] as $key => $text_field){
        $capture_field_vals .= $text_field .", ";
    }
}

//MySqli Insert Query
$insert_row = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO table ( captured_fields ) VALUES( $capture_field_vals )");

if($insert_row){
    print 'Success! ID of last inserted record is : ' .$mysqli->insert_id .'<br />';
}
?>
```

thanks in advance :)

Comment: `INSERT INTO table ( captured_fields )` or `INSERT INTO table ( $captured_fields )`?

Comment: You need to look at prepared statements. This is a bad way to build a query, and your mistake is just one reason why. Where are your quotes?

Comment: I have a lot of repetition , what's the solution @developerwjk

Comment: I have a lot of repetition , what's the solution @miken32

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `table` name is set in the query. Also a form submit button would be nice.

```
<?php
IF (isset($_POST["mytext"])){   

    $capture_field_vals ="";
    foreach($_POST["mytext"] as $key => $text_field){
        $capture_field_vals .= $text_field .", ";
    }

    $capture_field_vals = rtrim($capture_field_vals, ", "); // strip trailing comma space.

    IF (!empty($capture_field_vals)) {

      // Open a new connection to the MySQL server
      $mysqli = new mysqli('host','username','password','database_name');

      //Output any connection error
      IF ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
      }

      // mysqli insert
      $sql_ins = "INSERT INTO this_table (captured_fields) VALUES ($capture_field_vals)";
      $insert_row = $mysqli->query($sql_ins);
      IF ($insert_row){
        print 'Success! ID of last inserted record is : ' .$mysqli->insert_id .'<br />';
      }ELSE{
        print 'Insert Failed!<br />';
      }

    }ELSE{
      print 'capture_field_vals is empty!<br />';
    }

}ELSE{
    print 'Form not submitted!<br />';
}
?>
```